# Object call from PHP form submit not setting properties in object/class

Tags: php, oop

I have a User object which I use throughout the project with no problem. This User object is created when logged into the site and is initialized on a nav/header file attached to the frontend PHP file.

I have designed a simple set method that takes in a string. Later in a different place, the get method (getStockSearchParam) should return an array with two values. I am finding that when the form is submitted and the string is passed to the set method (setStockSearchParam) the get method returns completely empty. I am not even receiving error messages, it's almost like the form is completely bypassing the set method.

1. I have been using printR to check the contents of the get method return array.
2. For troubleshooting purposes, I manually initialized the properties from within the class and when the get method is called it returns with the values as expected. From this, I can assume my getter method is not the problem but a problem with the set method only from within the form submission process.
3. I have called the get & set methods from within the PHP page (not going through the "form submission" process) and that seems to work fine and the get method returns an array with values.
4. To troubleshoot I manually input a string parameter instead of using the value from the form input, but still with unsuccessful return results.

```html
<!-- SUBMISSION FORM ON FRONTEND PHP -->
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="symbol-search-input" placeholder="Symbol">
    <input id="stock-search-submit" name="symbol-search-btn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

```php
/* THIS IS LOCATED AT THE TOP OF THE FRONTEND PHP & USED FOR THE SUBMISSION FORM PROCESS */
require "includes/nav-header.php";

if(isset($_POST['symbol-search-btn'])) {
    $symbolInput = $_POST['symbol-search-input'];

    if(empty($symbolInput)){
        header("Location: testdir.php?error=emptyfield");
        exit();
    } else {
        strtoupper($symbolInput);

        if($user-> getStockData($symbolInput, "exist") == "found") {
            //The line below is where the error is occuring
            $user-> setStockSearchParam($symbolInput);

            header("Location: testdir.php?symbolsearch=success");
            exit();
        } else {
            header("Location: testdir.php?error=symbolnotfound");
        exit();
        }
    }
}
```

```php
/* THIS IS THE NAV/HEADER FILE CREATED/INCLUDED IN FRONTEND PHP WHEN USER LOGS IN, ALSO USED TO CREATE/USE USER OBJECT */
$dirPre = 'classes/';
$dirPost = '.class.php';

include $dirPre . 'user' . $dirPost;

$indexPage = "index2.php";

session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['userId']) {
    header("Location: " . $indexPage);
    exit();
}

$user = new User();
$user->setUserId($_SESSION['userId']);
```

```php
class User {

    private $symbolInput;
    private $symbolSearchPrice;

    public function getStockSearchParam() {

        $stockSearchData = array(
            'symbol' => $this->symbolInput,
            'price' => $this->symbolSearchPrice
        );

        return $stockSearchData;
    }

    public function setStockSearchParam($symbol) {

        $this->symbolInput = $symbol;
        $this->symbolSearchPrice = 4.99; //demo/test value
    }
}
```

When get method (getStockSearchParam) is called I expect an array to return with set values for the "symbol" index & the "price" index. All the get method is returning at this moment is an empty array. FYI, this is only happening upon form submission/process. Both the setter and getter method work fine within the PHP/outside of the form submit.

Comment: Does `getStockSearchParam()` work if you call it immediately after the problem line?

Comment: That is, if you run `$user->setStockSearchParam($symbolInput); $user->getStockSearchParam();` right in a row, does it give you the expected result?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't appear to display anything. I even tried a simple echo or print_r to test it (w/ random string in it). It is not displaying on the front end. Could this be a scope issue? I don't see why it wouldn't display the echo. I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you see the output if you substitute that for `echo "Test";` at that location?

Comment: I did both echo "test" & print_r ("test") with no result. Not even an error message on frontend. I'll usually get some error messages of some sort. However I assume it's successfully entering that "if" statement based on the success message in the URL/header.

Comment: Well, it would be blanking out your echo if you're seeing that success message. Does it change anything if you exit immediately after the echo (before you set the header)?

Comment: I commented out the header/location code and only left the echo (I also tried it with print_r)  it does successfully show it on the front end, however, it erases all other page elements only displaying the echo now.

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is that the `header()` function sets an HTTP header.  When you set that and exit, it kills the process and dumps everything that is currently in memory.  If you set `$user` in your current scope like that, the moment you hit the `exit()`, it will be lost.

Try using the `$_SESSION` variable for the user object, as well as for the id.

```
$_SESSION["user"] = new User();
$_SESSION["user"]->setUserId($_SESSION['userId']);
//other code
$_SESSION["user"]->setStockSearchParam($symbolInput);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I ended up having to rewrite the DB connection class, adding a _sleep & _wake function. From what I have read Session/Objects disconnect from the DB. I got rid of a lot of the errors, but the last one I was presented with was there is not enough space and that the object, session variable is too big.

Comment: If that User object is too big for the session, your other option is to take the string `$symbolInput` and save that to the session, then build the user object from that input in `testdir.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the end goal wasn't so serious that required for me to restructure the entire project. I ended up just designing something with JS, which I didn't want to do because the API token is public, but it's a free API & it's not a production project. I just wanted to finish this portfolio project for an interview. In the future I will implement something with Node JS to better protect the API token.